# GetCurrentHwProfile in Code::Blocks (C)

Tags: c, undefined

I am trying to get the GUID from windows in C in the Code::Blocks IDE with the following code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void getHWID()
{
    HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;

    if(GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo))
    {
        printf("Hardware GUID: %s\n",    hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid);
        printf("Hardware Profile: %s\n", hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileName);
    }
}
```

I keep getting these errors even though I am linking and including all the files required:

> In function 'getHWID': warning:
>   implicit declaration of function
>   'GetCurrentHwProfile'
>
> In function `getHWID': undefined
>   reference to`GetCurrentHwProfile'
>
> ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 1
>   warnings ===|

Let me know if anyone has had this problem or know how to fix it. Also if I right click `HW_PROFILE_INFO` or `GetCurrentHwProfile` and click *Find Declaration* it says not found.

I would like to get this to work, but I am also open to other simple ways to get this done.

edit: I've included Winbase.h now and it found a declaration for `HW_PROFILE_INFO` but I still get a undefined reference error for `GetCurrentHwProfile`

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured Code::Blocks to include the correct SDK (I believe this function is part of the Windows SDK)? I suggest using Microsoft Visual Studio to write Windows code.

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is all you need to do, but there is a section in the their [wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_a_supported_compiler#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B.2B) about how to use the Microsoft's compiler.

Comment: i've been using codeblocks for all my windows programming with GCC as my compiler and this is the only problem i've ever ran into (i mostly do winsock programming) i installed the MS SDK and that didn't help either(i linked AdvAPI32.lib also which is supposedly what this function uses and still no go)... so i am still clueless as to what is wrong.

Comment: Linking a library won't magically make missing symbols get declared. You need to include the win32 headers.

Comment: Ain't the headers being included at line 2?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
GetCurrentHwProfile
```

to

```
GetCurrentHwProfileA
```

or add

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetCurrentHwProfile GetCurrentHwProfileW
#else
#define GetCurrentHwProfile GetCurrentHwProfileA
#endif
```

have a look [GetCurrentHwProfile was not declared in this scope using MinGW's g++ compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544526/getcurrenthwprofile-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-using-mingws-g-compiler)