# GetCurrentHwProfile was not declared in this scope using MinGW's g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I've been trying to get the Hardware GUID, and I found this function posted on the web.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main()
{
    HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;

    if(GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo) != NULL){
            printf("Hardware GUID: %s\n",    hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid);
            printf("Hardware Profile: %s\n", hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileName);
    }else{
            return 0;
    }

    getchar();
}
```

The problem is, whenever I try to compile it, I get "error: 'GetCurrentHwProfile' was not declared in this scope". I'm using MinGW's G++. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice catch! (if you could call it that)

The problem is that normally GetCurrentHwProfile would be a short-cut, if you like. When compiling with UNICODE support it gets changed into GetCurrentHwProfileW. Otherwise, it gets changed to GetCurrentHwProfileA.

The solution?
Simply add an A on the end. I.e GetCurrentHwProfileA
:)

BB.b.b.ut - remember you have to change it explictly if you decide to use unicode after-all. A much cleaner solution would be to make GetCurrentHwProfile refer to the correct one as needed. I guess it's likely done with something like: (too lazy to look right now. All the windows functions use this trick, guess the minGW crowd missed this little gem that is  GetCurrentHwProfile)

```
#ifdef UNICODE
 #define GetCurrentHwProfile GetCurrentHwProfileW
#else
 #define GetCurrentHwProfile GetCurrentHwProfileA
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `GetCurrentHwProfile()` is declared in the `winbase.h` header:

```
WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI GetCurrentHwProfileA(LPHW_PROFILE_INFOA);
WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI GetCurrentHwProfileW(LPHW_PROFILE_INFOW);
```

Note that it is either `GetCurrentHwProfileA` (for Ansi) or `GetCurrentHwProfileW` (for Unicode / wide characters). I can find no sign of a macro which aliases `GetCurrentHwProfile` to either of the two functions, depending on a defined `UNICODE`.

So, the current solution seems to use either `GetCurrentHwProfileA` or `GetCurrentHwProfileW` or do something like

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetCurrentHwProfile GetCurrentHwProfileW
#else
#define GetCurrentHwProfile GetCurrentHwProfileA
#endif
```